# Storybook in Create React App withTypeScript still compiles when component has illegal types

Tags: typescript, storyboard, create-react-app

Im trying to add Storybook to Create React App and have everything in TypeScript. I've got it compiling however when I have illegal types in a React component then Create React App errors (as it should) but Storybook still compiles.

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "hiit5",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/core": "^10.0.15",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.17",
    "@types/node": "^12.7.2",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.5",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-docgen-typescript-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-info": "^5.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.1.11",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.1.11",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.1.11",
    "@types/storybook__react": "^4.0.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "react-docgen-typescript-loader": "^3.1.1",
    "storybook-addon-jsx": "^7.1.5"
  }
}
```

Root tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

.storybook/config.ts

```
import { configure } from "@storybook/react";

// automatically import all files ending in *.stories.js
const req = require.context("../stories", true, /\.stories\.tsx$/);
function loadStories() {
  req.keys().forEach(filename => req(filename));
}

configure(loadStories, module);
```

.storybook/tsconfig.ts

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build/lib",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "es7", "es2017", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDirs": ["src", "stories"],
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build", "scripts"]
}
```

.storybook/webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = ({ config, mode }) => {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
    loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
    options: {
      presets: [["react-app", { flow: false, typescript: true }]]
    }
  });
  config.resolve.extensions.push(".ts", ".tsx");
  return config;
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason Storybook still compiles despite type errors is that Babel preset `"react-app"` from Create React App (CRA) only strips off the TypeScript definitions and emits all files without further compiler checks.

[`react-app` / `babel-preset-react-app`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-react-app) can carry the CRA Babel configuration over to other builds, like Storybook. Internally, it is [based](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/v3.1.1/packages/babel-preset-react-app/package.json#L35) on [@babel/preset-typescript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Babel-Starter), which handles .ts/tsx files like this:

> While Babel can take over compiling/transpiling – doing things like erasing your types and rewriting the newest ECMAScript features to work in older runtimes – it doesn’t have type-checking built in, and still requires using TypeScript to accomplish that. So even if Babel builds successfully, you might need to check in with TypeScript to catch type errors. [Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/typescript-and-babel-7)

### Solution

#### 1.) `babel-preset-react-app`

Stick with `babel-preset-react-app` and use `tsc` to check for compile errors. The [Microsoft/TypeScript-Babel-Starter](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Babel-Starter) repository shows how to configure npm scripts that run a type check with `tsc`:

```
"type-check": "tsc --noEmit",
"type-check:watch": "npm run type-check -- --watch",
```

Those scripts could be further wrapped by some IDE task (e.g. if you use VS Code).

#### 2.) Full-fledged compiler, e.g. `awesome-typescript-loader`

Use some Webpack TypeScript loader like `awesome-typescript-loader` that makes use of the full compiler during bundling ([Link](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/typescript-config/#setting-up-typescript-to-work-with-storybook)).

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = ({ config, mode }) => {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
    loader: "awesome-typescript-loader"
  });
  config.resolve.extensions.push(".ts", ".tsx");
  return config;
};
```

### Settings

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    // if you use awesome-typescript-loader
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  // include stories and src for type checking
  "include": ["src", "stories"]
}
```

Comment: Hello. Do you have any idea how to do the opposite of this? When I run yarn storybook, storybook compiles even with errors. However, when I run yarn build-storybook, the build fails because of type errors. I want the same functionality as the dev build. This is with CRA --typescript template

Comment: If you want to execute `yarn storybook` only if there are no compile errors, probably the easiest solution is to prepend a type check like above `type-check` script. For example `yarn type-check && yarn storybook` - you could add this as npm script as well.

Comment: On the contrary, I want to run yarn build-storybook even though there are type errors.